# How to change cpu frequency using c code?

Tags: c, linux

I am working on an energy saving algorithm for which I want to change the frequency of the CPU for saving the energy so I need C code so that I can change the frequency of the CPU.I tried below code, but the problem with the code is that it directly execute the Linux command and the command needs root permission.Is there any way to change the CPU frequency using C code.

My Code is...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
 int main(){
     char cmd[]="sudo cpufreq-set -c 1 -f 1862Mhz";
     system(cmd);
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Run your program with root permissions?

Comment: There's not an alternative way to change the CPU frequency from a C program that doesn't require root privilege, if that's what you mean to ask. What's your use case for this?

Comment: @lurker I am working on an energy saving algorithm for which I want to change the speed of the CPU for saving the energy so I need C code so that I can change the speed of the CPU.

Comment: For testing purposes, you may have to run your programs as `root`. But in a multitasking system like Linux, how would you arbitrate between several user tasks that might want to change the CPU speed at different times and/or different values?

Comment: Actually, it will be done at the time of scheduling decision.The algorithm will use the data from the previous time interval and will take the decision for the speed of the CPU for the current interval.

Comment: You can use `cpufrequtils-devel` instead of running the utility via `system()`. Make your code `setuid()` to root, or run it as root. Include `cpufreq.h` and link with `-lcpufreq`. This prototype in `cpufreq.h` is what you need `extern int cpufreq_set_frequency(unsigned int cpu, unsigned long target_frequency);`.

Answer (score 2):

This is the kernel's job to throttle up and down the CPU frequency.
As a user space application you don't have enough information about other processes that currently use the system.

even f if you run as root and you have the ability to issue such a command, the whole concept is wrong.

look for `DVFS` kernel drivers, that's how you do it.